# type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Double

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stack-trace

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class merge_sort 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, how many numbers there should be in the array?");
    int Size=input.nextInt();
    Double A []=new Double [Size] ;
    System.out.println("Please enter "+ (Size+1)+" real numbers");
    for (int z=0;z<Size;z++)
        A[z]=input.nextDouble();
    int p=0,q=(Size/2+1),r=(Size-1);//assuming that the array with even length.
    int L []=new int [4] ;//the left side, sorted array
    int R []=new int [4] ;//the right side, sorted array
    L[0]=7;L[1]=6;L[2]=2;L[3]=1;
    R[0]=5;R[1]=4;R[2]=3;R[3]=8;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        System.out.print(L[i]);
    System.out.println("");
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        System.out.print(R[j]);

 merge(L,R);        
}
```

---

I have an error in this line of the code:

```
A[z]=input.nextDouble();
```

The error is : **type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Double**

I am stuck couple of hours, can someone help me with that?

Comment: please check which version of java you are using.. Please add error `stack trace` to Identify the problem because autoboxing will automatically done after java V1.5. @Nahorai

Comment: Its working fine to me (Java v_1.7) because of autoboxing feature.

Comment: The compiler error is pretty clear. Case matters, `Double` is a wrapper class for the primitive type `double`, they are not the same. Either change your array : `double A []= new double[Size]` or change the assignemnt: `A[z]=new Double(input.nextDouble());`

Comment: @SaschaKolberg  what about the new cool feature of `java` named `autoboxing` ??

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Well, it is cool! But the question clearly indicates that is not happening for him. I am just assuming there is a reason for the op  not to use a java version with cooler features ;)

Comment: @SaschaKolberg If Feature like `autoboxing ` is there then why need of invoking the `constructor` of `Double ` Class ?? just using by a `new ` Operator `new Double (double args)` ?

Comment: OMG guys... autoboxing is really NOT cool. Rather for guys that don't grasp the basic difference between primitives, reference types, new Double(); and Double.valueOf(); - Getting in trouble with == comparisons latrr on^^. Seriously, I even consider the autoboxing/autoconversion feature a big design flaw. That's what explicit conversions/casts actually should be for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double` is a `class` type. `nextDouble` returns the primitive type `double`. Change `A` to `double` array

```
double[] A = new double[Size];
```

Comment: @Guy what about the autoboxing feature in `java`. why `nextDouble()` returned value will not be autoboxed into a `Double`?? Please explain this

Answer (score 0):

Such as Guy's answer, or you can change line:

```
A[z]=input.nextDouble();
```

to:

```
A[z]=new Double(input.nextDouble());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do this.

1. By Invoking `constructor` of `Double` Class using `new` Operator and passing the `input.nextDouble()`.

   ```
    A[z] = new Double(input.nextDouble());
   ```

2.
  A cool Feature introduced in and after java 1.5 named `autoboxing` So, You may also try this.

```
 A[z] = (Double)input.nextDouble();
```